# Image processing : Extract background class from annotated images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Given an image of dimensions aXb (see an example below), and a few rectangular annotations for different classes, what is the most effective (or non-brute-force) method for finding non-overlapping rectangular annotations (at least m X n dimension) not covered by the the already provided annotations? Basically I want rectangle annotations for background class.

[image]

In the above image green rectangles are annotations, while the red rectangles I marked are the background. I want to know the pixel coordinates for red boxes. Not all red boxes are needed, say any 5 boxes of minimum m X n dimension shall be sufficient.

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: To get help faster, why don't you mock (from GIMP, for example) your expected result?

Comment: @RafaelRuiz done that!